# Unable to compile regular expression in Fail2Ban

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I'm trying to get this regex working in Fail2Ban:

```
SRC=(?<ADDR>.*) DST.*(?=DPT=5003)
```

In a regex tester it's working very fine. When testing in Fail2Ban, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to compile regular expression 'SRC=(?\[?(?:(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<ip4>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})|(?P<ip6>(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}::?|::){1,7}(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|(?<=:):)))\]?.*) DST.*(?=DPT=5003)'
```

This is a line from the log I want to crawl:

```
Jul 14 13:30:44 servername kernel: [  803.539059] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=somemacadress SRC=somesourceip DST=somedestinationip LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=18692 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50852 DPT=5003 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Basically I want to block an IP if there is a block on DPT=5003

Can somebody help?

Thanks!

Comment: use `fail2ban-regex` to test your regex

Comment: I did, this is where the mentioned error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `SRC=(?<ADDR>.*) DST.*(?=DPT=5003)` uses PCRE named capture group syntax `?<ADDR>` which `fail2ban`, being written in Python, doesn't understand and doesn't use. You need to use `fail2ban` own substitution `<HOST>` to capture IP or hostname. See the [Developing Filters](https://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html) from `fail2ban` docs.

Update: `<ADDR>` substitution is also recognized, but isn't documented in the page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it'd be enough to fix the typo - either use `(?:...)` note `:`, or remove group parenthesis:

```
- SRC=(?<ADDR>.*) DST.*(?=DPT=5003)
+ SRC=<ADDR>.* DST.*(?=DPT=5003)
```

But this RE is vulnerable (no anchors, contains catch-all's etc)...
For better failregex example see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/2225#issuecomment-766087078